# Wordpress function error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On my my Wordpress category pages, I get the following message under the title of some posts

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/)        is not within the allowed path(s): (/nfs:/tmp:/usr/local:/etc/apache2/gs-bin) in     /nfs/c05/h05/mnt/158666/domains/oddschanger.com/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1335

for example http://oddschanger.com/category/fourfourtoms-football-talk/

This has happened since changing host to media temple... Any ideas what the error is?

Comment: You're trying to check if a file exists outside of the directories you're allowed to access.

Answer (score 1):

You can only access files within the allowed directories. The file the function is trying to access is `/`, which is outside what is allowed.

You are allowed to access

```
/nfs
/tmp
/usr/local
/etc/apache2/gs-bin
```

If this is a dedicated/virtual server you can edit this in your VirtualHost container.

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

There is a full explanation here: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2007/12/30/fixing-php-s-require-open_basedir-restri